# Error while making payments using Mollie API in php

Tags: php, mollie

I am making payments using mollie API in php. But its giving me some errors . I have posted my code and screenshot of the errors.

THIS IS MY CODE:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

try {
    require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

    $mollie = new \Mollie\Api\MollieApiClient();
    $mollie->setApiKey("test_XXXX");

    $orderId = time();

    $amount = $_POST['amount'];
    $payment = $mollie->payments->create([
        "amount" => [
            "currency" => "EUR",
            "value" => "$amount", // You must send the correct number of decimals, thus we enforce the use of strings
        ],
        "description" => "Order #{$orderId}",
        "redirectUrl" => "https://example.com/Mollie/return/".$orderId."/",
        "webhookUrl" => "https://example.com/Mollie/webhook/",
        "metadata" => [
            "order_id" => $orderId,
        ],
    ]);
    print_r($payment);

    $payment_data = array(
            'payment_id' => $payment->id,
            'user_id' => $_POST['user_id'],
            'order_id' => $orderId,
            'mode' => $payment->mode,
            'description' => $payment->description,
            'status' => $payment->status,
            'added_date' => date('Y-m-d'),
            'added_time' => date('H:i:s')
    );
    print_r($payment_data);

    header("Location: " . $payment->getCheckoutUrl(), true, 303);

} catch (\Mollie\Api\Exceptions\ApiException $e) {
    echo "API call failed: ". htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage());
}
```

THE SCREENSHOT:

1. The first image shows "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token M in JSON at position 0" in RED color.
2. The second image is the warning I am getting

[First image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCnYW.jpg)

[Second Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnPd2.jpg)

Comment: This is probably caused by a `print_r();` on line 31. You should not output before sending headers, it's a HTML thing, it wants the headers before the content.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I will try removing it and will get back here if its working. :)

Comment: KIKO Software- I have removed the print_r line and now that error has gone. But I don't know why $payment->getCheckoutUrl() is throwing 404 error.

Comment: A 404 error means that the URL doesn't exist. There's no harm in checking which URL your code returns, before you actually implement the redirection. Another method to the check the URL is to use the developer tools of your browser.